# Qt question to fullscreen flash application

Tags: c++, qt, flash

I am using Qt to develop an application and inside we have access to select flash streaming videos like youtube. Is there a way to programmaticly full screen the flash application without requiring interaction from the user?

I am using a "QWebView" control.

Comment: Turns out this is an intended limitation in flash: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=1394

So, I'm sorry I guess I asked a question that wasn't possible :\. I really think this is a serious limitation of Flash.

Comment: Locking upon request of the author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say: locate the button for the fullscreen application on the page, and send a click using QEVent. Tricky, but might work.

If the button is inside the flash application, you will have difficulties to locate it but if you succeed, you can probably send the click to the flash application area.

Answer (score 1):

try calling [showFullScreen](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.6/qwidget.html#showFullScreen) for the window where your QWebView control is hosted.

> void QWidget::showFullScreen ()
>   Shows the widget in full-screen
>   mode.
>
> Calling this function only affects
>   windows.
>
> To return from full-screen mode, call
>   showNormal().

Comment: I don't think that will fullscreen the flash application though. Basically I want to fullscreen the youtube video not the browser control.

Comment: oh..now I see what you need. How to you load youtube content into your application? I guess you should have some javascript or\and actionscript code running to interact with the player component; like it's shown here http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=youtube#chromeless_player. Now if you do running your code you can toggle full screen mode for the flash player using technique which is described here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/full_screen_mode_03.html

Answer (score 0):

You can always inject javascript from Qt into your QWebPage. If there is a javascript API for forcing the flash viewer to full screen, I do not know.